# Anyone else having trouble updating XCode to 4.3.1?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, osx-lion

I have two MacBook Airs (One is the newest version).  On both of them I have tried to install the new version of XCode via the Mac App Store.  Both of them downloaded and indicate that it installed, but XCode still reports 4.2.1 and I can't deploy apps to my phone because it is running 5.1 and the SDK is missing from XCode.

Anyone else having similar issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably didn't uninstall the old version of Xcode, so you have two versions of Xcode:

1. Xcode 4.2.1 in **/Developer/Applications**
2. Xcode 4.3.1 in **/Applications**: All the content that was previously in **/Developer** is now packaged inside **/Applications/Xcode.app**.

You can launch the new version of Xcode from the **/Applications** folder, and it will ask you to uninstall the old version.

Comment: Actually once you run the new Xcode it will request to remove the old installation by moving **/Developer** to the trash.

Comment: That was edzachary it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you download through the app store?  I did and the Xcode icon in my dock still points to Xcode 4.2 but the new Xcode, 4.3 is in the launch pad area.